# scons and ObjC++

Tags: objective-c, macos, scons

I'm trying to use `scons` to build a cross-platform cpp project.  Some of the files contain ObjC code, which is only included on OSX and hidden behind `ifdef` guards on other platforms.

On OSX, I need to include a few `-framework` compiler/linker options, which I do through

```
 env.AppendUnique(FRAMEWORKS = Split('Cocoa CoreAudio AudioToolbox AudioUnit GLUT OpenGL'))
```

in my `SConstruct` file as it says in the docs.

However, the `FRAMEWORKS` variable only gets used for `.m` and `.mm` files, whereas mine all have the `.cpp` extension. I want to keep it this way, since they're only ObjC files on OSX, and just cpp on other platforms.

Is there a way to get `scons` to treat source files with a `.cpp` extension as ObjC++, to get it to use the `FRAMEWORKS` env var?

Comment: Can you tell us which Tool you are currently using, while trying to compile the "*.cpp" files? This boils down to the question: "How do you setup your build environment?".

Comment: @dirkbaechle I'm trying to use `clang++` for the compiler and linker.  So I've got  `env.Replace(CXX = 'clang++')` and `env.Replace(LD = 'clang++')`

Comment: This wasn't quite what I was aiming at. How do you initialize your Environment "env", are you using any special Tools especially designed to support ObjC (there are some out there, as my friend Google told me...)?

Comment: @dirkbaechle ah sorry mate, it's [up on GH](https://github.com/digego/extempore/blob/scons-build/SConstruct#L203). Not using any special tools as far as I can tell (most of the OSX-specific setup stuff happens in [`configure_environment_darwin`](https://github.com/digego/extempore/blob/scons-build/SConstruct#L271))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the sources of the current version 2.3.4 and there is no support for the FRAMEWORKS variable when compiling source files, only for linking (applelink.py Tool).
So you'd have to define your own ObjC Builder, which then could use the already defined variables like $_FRAMEWORKPATH, $_FRAMEWORKS and $FRAMEWORKSFLAGS.
If you need more help with that, you might want to come over to our user mailing list scons-users@scons.org ( http://www.scons.org/lists.php ) where we could talk you through all the gory details. ;)

Comment: Ok, thanks very much for your help. I'll add it to the to-do list :)